# Replace prototype objects property

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>

    Croppic = function (id, options) {

        var that = this;
        that.id = id;
        that.obj = $('#' + id);
        that.outputDiv = that.obj;


    };
    Croppic.prototype = {
        form: {}
    };

    init: function () {
        var that = this;

        var cropControlUpload = '';
        if (that.options.customUploadButtonId === '') {
            cropControlUpload = '<i class="cropControlUpload"></i>';
        }
        var cropControlRemoveCroppedImage = '<i class="cropControlRemoveCroppedImage"></i>';

        if ($.isEmptyObject(that.croppedImg)) {
            cropControlRemoveCroppedImage = '';
        }
        if (!$.isEmptyObject(that.options.loadPicture)) {
            cropControlUpload = '';
        }

        var html = '<div class="cropControls cropControlsUpload"> ' + cropControlUpload + cropControlRemoveCroppedImage + ' </div>';

        that.outputDiv.append(html);
        var formHtml = '<form class="' + that.id + '_imgUploadForm" style="visibility: hidden;">  <input type="file" name="img" accept="image/*" id="' + that.id + '_imgUploadField">  </form>';
        that.outputDiv.append(formHtml);
        that.form = that.outputDiv.find('.' + that.id + '_imgUploadForm');

    },
    reset:function (){
        var that=this;
        that.init();//This initializes using init function
    }
</script>
```

I have a crop module which does something like above.So everytime reset is called the module is initialized by using the init function.

However, the output is not coming as expected what is happening that when a reset is called more than twice, the form object shows this kind of behavior.

That is what console shows when reset is called the first time.Look for the property **0**.
[image]

When the reset is called twice the result is something like this.Instead of removing the property **0** , it appended a new property **1**.
[image]

This thing go on if i make more calls to the reset.

So when this  happens **Inspector** in Mozilla shows more than one form when reset is called more than one time(Here i have called reset twice hence two forms in **Inspector**).
[image]

To overcome this problem i tried deleting the property **0** and even tried deleting the whole object and tried to create a new object but nothing helps.

```
   if(that.form.hasOwnProperty("0"))
        {
          delete that.form["0"];// Here i even did this delete that.form;
          that.form = that.outputDiv.find('.' + that.id + '_imgUploadForm');
         }else{
                that.form = that.outputDiv.find('.' + that.id + '_imgUploadForm');
              }
```

I did everything but the same thing happens.How do i make sure it doesn't add more properties if **0** exists .If **0** exists just replace **0** by the new one.

**Full Code** :http://codepad.org/03EiunbL

Comment: Whenever you call reset, it calls init, which creates a new form.  The `delete` command only remove JavaScript property, not the value, and your form will stay at the same place in DOM.  How to remove / replace DOM elements is a common question on SO.

Comment: @Sheepy Yes i want to remove the DOM Elements i.e replace the new form with the old one

Comment: @Sheepy Could you answer with considering the above example?

Comment: @Sheepy `cropContainerEyecandy.parentNode.replaceChild( that.outputDiv.find('.' + that.id + '_imgUploadForm'));` i did something this but it doesn't bind the events.What now ?